# Ruby Program Error: NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, textmate

I typed up a simple Ruby code for a tutorial question, as shown below.

```
#Grandma is deaf!  
puts "Hey Sonny! It's your lovely Grandmother! How are you?"  
response = gets.chomp  
while response != "BYE"  
  if response != response.upcase  
    puts "Huh?! I CAN'T HEAR YOU!"  
  else  
    puts "NO! NOT SINCE " + (1930 + rand(21)).to_s + "!"  
  end  
  response = gets.chomp  
end  
puts "GOOD BYE, SONNY!"
```

However, when I run this, the window displays:

```
Hey Sonny! It's your lovely Grandmother! How are you?  
NoMethodError: private method ‘chomp’ called for nil:NilClass

at top level in deafGrandma.rb at line 3
```

I don't understand why `chomp` is not recognized. I'm using textMate on a Mac I have Ruby version 1.8.7, which should be fine. Any solutions?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: You should edit your question and indent your code with four spaces to preserve the indentation/formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrian is right about interactive input being disabled in TextMate 1.5.9 (r1510). [See this post from TextMate's developer](http://blog.macromates.com/2009/interactive-input/).

However, you can upgrade to a "cutting-edge" TextMate release that restores interactive input, and will allow you to run the above code just fine. Go to TextMate's `Preferences -> Software Updates` and make sure `Automatically check for updates` is checked.

Select `Cutting-Edge` in the `Watch For:` dropdown menu. Finally, click `Check Now`. The latest release (r1589) should automatically download. Interactive input is re-enabled in this release.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer, and welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Cmd-R shortcut in TextMate to run your code, you will not be able to supply it input because textmate only supports output. You will have to run it in a terminal instead. The reason you are getting that error is because `$stdin` is closed, so `gets` returns `nil`.